# Django login not working. Page just refreshes a new login page

Tags: django

I have a project called django_swing. Within this project i have 2 different app. One is interface and the other is users.
Within the django_swing folder for urls.py, I have the following:

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
```

Within login.html, I have the following:

```
<form action="#">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" required="" placeholder="Enter username">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <a href="pages-recoverpw.html" class="text-muted float-right"><small>Forgot your password?</small></a>
   <label for="password">Password</label>
    <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
     <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password">
      <div class="input-group-append" data-password="false">
       <div class="input-group-text">
        <span class="password-eye"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group mb-3">
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="checkbox-signin" checked>
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox-signin">Remember me</label>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group mb-0 text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Log In </button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Within the interface folder for urls.py, I have the following:

```
path('', views.home, name='interface-home'),
```

Within the interface folder for views.py, I have the following:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'interface/home.html', {'title':'Home'} )
```

I have the file for home.html. As it is very long, I cant paste here. When i run the project, 127.0.0.1 loads the page for home.html.

Lastly, within the django_swing folder for settings.py, I have the following at the bottom of the file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='interface-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

But when i access `127.0.0.1/login` and key in with a account i just made followed by pressing the login button, the page refreshes with the same login page and the url becomes `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?#`. It is not jumping to `interface-home` as declared in settings.py. Can anyone advise me on how to solve this? I am a beginner at this. Thank you very much!

After editing the errors pointed out, i click login and got this the error of page not found for `login/post`

How come though?

Comment: You have a custom login template `users/login.html`? Can you share it's contents?

Comment: I have added in the form part of ```users/login.html``` @IainShelvington

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template has several issues

Your form method needs to be "post", the login view is expecting a POST request, and you shouldn't pass anything in the `action` attribute

```
<form method="post">
```

You also need to provide "name" parameters to your inputs so that their values are submitted with that name

```
<input id="username" name="username" ... >
<input id="password" name="password" ... >
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! But I am encountering another issue now as page is not found after login. How do i solve this? I edited my post to describe the scenario at the bottom

Comment: @L.Calvin Did you pass `action="post"` instead of `method="post"` in the form tag?

Comment: Sorry about it. I thought i saved it by pressing ```ctrl s``` but it didnt saved. Problem solved. Thank you !